# WebRequest from Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project in which I store data to a local folder. I want to send those data to a server using a ftp client. How can I perform so in Unity? Is it a way to do so? Any library or a software like filezilla with which I can perform?

I came across [webRequest class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) however I am not sure how to use it. I came across the suggested code from the answer however I am not sure how I am going to use it. I got an error from the `FTPupload` function located inside the `onGUI()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. I guess this is the usage you're looking for:
https://github.com/mminer/ftpuploader-unity/blob/master/Editor/Uploader.cs

Scroll down to `Upload` method; I used the same many times and it works pretty well.

[EDIT]
Here's a sample of the aboves code than can be used directly in your Unity project:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Net;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//CLASS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class FTPUpload : MonoBehaviour
{    
    #region Methods
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //METHODS
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void CallThisWithButton()
    {
        Upload("PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE", "YOUR_FTP_SERVER_ADRESS", "YOUR_USERNAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD", "ANY_SUB_FOLDER");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uploads a file through FTP.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The path to the file to upload.</param>
    /// <param name="server">The server to use.</param>
    /// <param name="username">The username to use.</param>
    /// <param name="password">The password to use.</param>
    /// <param name="initialPath">The path on the server to upload to.</param>
    static void Upload(string filename, string server, string username, string password, string initialPath)
    {
        Debug.Log("Upload started.");

        var file = new FileInfo(filename);
        var address = new Uri("ftp://" + server + "/" + Path.Combine(initialPath, file.Name));
        var request = FtpWebRequest.Create(address) as FtpWebRequest;

        // Upload options:

        // Provide credentials
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        // Set control connection to closed after command execution
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        // Specify command to be executed
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // Specify data transfer type
        request.UseBinary = true;

        // Notify server about size of uploaded file
        request.ContentLength = file.Length;

        // Set buffer size to 2KB.
        var bufferLength = 2048;
        var buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        var contentLength = 0;

        // Open file stream to read file
        var fs = file.OpenRead();

        try
        {
            // Stream to which file to be uploaded is written.
            var stream = request.GetRequestStream();

            // Read from file stream 2KB at a time.
            contentLength = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

            // Loop until stream content ends.
            while (contentLength != 0)
            {
                //Debug.Log("Progress: " + ((fs.Position / fs.Length) * 100f));
                // Write content from file stream to FTP upload stream.
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
                contentLength = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

            // Close file and request streams
            stream.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error uploading file: " + e.Message);
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("Upload successful.");
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #endregion
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: I have already came across the proposed class. However I am not sure how I will use it from my code. I want inside a button, when the button is pressed to send data to my server using the ftpuploader. I copy the file to my project and I got error with  FTPUpload (method or class?) I got not defined error.

Comment: Shouldnt be Upload instead of FTPUpload?

Comment: @JoseRamon I edited my first answer so you can find an example of code you should be able to copy/paste to your project.

Keep in mind I use UI 4.6 Button to call `CallThisWIthButton()` method. Also, make sure your path to your file is correct : \\ instead of \ (mine looked like `C:\\Users\\Roy\\Desktop\\test_file.txt` and that the path you're aiming for on your FTP server already exists ;)